# Replace sequence of words in string with string python

Tags: python, string, replace, find, findall

I couldn't find anything that could solve this (`replace()` method doesn't work).

I have a sentence like:

```
sentence_noSlots = "Albania compared to other CountriesThe Internet users of Albania is similar to that of Poland , Portugal , Russia , Macedonia , Saudi Arabia , Argentina , Greece , Dominica , Azerbaijan , Italy with a respective Internet users of 62.8 , 62.1 , 61.4 , 61.2 , 60.5 , 59.9 , 59.9 , 59.0 , 58.7 , 58.5 -LRB- per 100 people -RRB- and a global rank of 62 , 63 , 64 , 65 , 66 , 68 , 69 , 70 , 71 , 72.10 years growthAlbania 's Internet users had a positive growth of 5,910 -LRB- % -RRB- in the last 10 years from -LRB- 2003 to 2013 -RRB- ."
```

I then have a string like:

```
extracted_country = Saudi Arabia 
extracted_value = 58.5
```

I need to replace `Saudi Arabia` in the string with `<location>empty</location>` and `58.5` with `<number>empty</number>`. My current method is:

```
sentence_noSlots.replace(str(extracted_country),"<location>empty</location>")
sentence_noSlots.replace(str(extracted_value),"<number>empty</number>")
```

However because Saudi Arabia is two words, a simple word replace doesn't work. Nor does tokenizing first and replacing work due to the same type of issue:

```
 sentenceTokens = sentence_noSlots.split()
                            for i,token in enumerate(sentenceTokens):
                                if token==extracted_country:
                                    sentenceTokens[i]="<location>empty</location>"
                                if token==extracted_value:
                                    sentenceTokens[i]="<number>empty</number>"
                            sentence_noSlots = (" ").join(sentenceTokens)
```

How can I achieve what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.replace()` is not in-place. Strings are immutable in python.

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace]) Return a copy of string s
>   with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional
>   argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are
>   replaced.

Do this:

```
>>> sentence_noSlots = "Albania compared to other CountriesThe Internet users of Albania is similar to that of Poland , Portugal , Russia , Macedonia , Saudi Arabia , Argentina , Greece , Dominica , Azerbaijan , Italy with a respective Internet users of 62.8 , 62.1 , 61.4 , 61.2 , 60.5 , 59.9 , 59.9 , 59.0 , 58.7 , 58.5 -LRB- per 100 people -RRB- and a global rank of 62 , 63 , 64 , 65 , 66 , 68 , 69 , 70 , 71 , 72.10 years growthAlbania 's Internet users had a positive growth of 5,910 -LRB- % -RRB- in the last 10 years from -LRB- 2003 to 2013 -RRB- ."
>>> 
>>> extracted_country = "Saudi Arabia"
>>> extracted_value = 58.5
>>> s = sentence_noSlots.replace(str(extracted_country),"<location>empty</location>").replace(str(extracted_value),"<number>empty</number>")
>>> s
"Albania compared to other CountriesThe Internet users of Albania is similar to that of Poland , Portugal , Russia , Macedonia , <location>empty</location> , Argentina , Greece , Dominica , Azerbaijan , Italy with a respective Internet users of 62.8 , 62.1 , 61.4 , 61.2 , 60.5 , 59.9 , 59.9 , 59.0 , 58.7 , <number>empty</number> -LRB- per 100 people -RRB- and a global rank of 62 , 63 , 64 , 65 , 66 , 68 , 69 , 70 , 71 , 72.10 years growthAlbania 's Internet users had a positive growth of 5,910 -LRB- % -RRB- in the last 10 years from -LRB- 2003 to 2013 -RRB- ."
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant:

```
extracted_country = "Saudi Arabia"
extracted_value = "58.5"
```

Then, the .replace method works as expected. Be careful though, it is NOT a modifier: it returns a NEW string with the modification. "sentence_noSlots" will remain the same.

So by chaining both .replace you can achieve it like this:

```
sentence_slots = sentence_noSlots.replace(str(extracted_country),"<location>empty</location>").replace(str(extracted_value),"<number>empty</number>")
```